# Run to function on all sheets except one

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a script that runs a function on all eight sheets:

```
function newfunktion(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s=0; s<sheets.length; s++) {
     zero(sheets[s], 'sheet');
  }
}

function zero(sheet, type) {
  var data, range;
  if(type === 'sheet') {
    var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
    var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();   
   Logger.log(lastColumn);
    range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 200, 16);
  } else {
    range = sheet;
  }
  data = range.getValues();
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    for(var j = 0, jLen = data[0].length; j < jLen; j++) {
      if(!data[i][j]) {
        data[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }  
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

We don't want it to run on the last sheet called 'Summary'.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sheets.length - 1` to skip processing last sheet.

Comment: Something like this:  for (var s=0; s<sheets.length -1; s++)